# How customize Identity view in Aspnet core 3 Angular template

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

Just creating a new project, using Aspnet Core 3.0 with Angular and Identity with visual Studio 19 template for this project.

How can I customize the login, register and other identity pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Asp.net Core Identity, it uses Identity library which is Razor Page.

You could follow steps below:

Right Click Project->Add New Scaffolded Item-> Identity-> Add-> Choose files to override-> Select Data context class-> Add

And then, change the generated Razor Page based on your requirement.

Comment: Is it possible to create Angular components to login instead these razor pages ?